# IIS Can't connect to remote database

Tags: php, iis, mysqli

I have a website on IIS and want to access a database on a remote host.

my code:

```
$this->db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

I get this error:

> Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die
>   Verbindung verweigerte

In english its like

> Remote Host refused connection

Default Port is 3306, when I execute

```
$this->db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);
```

I get the same result.

Via cmd telnet I can't connect to $hostname 3306, but to $hostname 1433.

So I tried

```
$this->db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname, 1433);
```

But this isn't working either. I get

> mysqli::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away
>
> mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=3276

Do you know how I can get the connection to the database?

Comment: Port 1433 are for MSSQL, not MySQL. What kind of SQL server are you trying to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the info in your question, it looks like the remote database is SQL Server, not MySQL. Therefore you need to use PHP's MSSQL library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

It usually requires additional installation/configuration though.

Comment: I am feeling a bit silly now ... Yes it is MS SQL Server. I installed sqlsrv plus I had to install odbc and it is now working with $this->db = sqlsrv_connect($hostname, array("Database" => $dbname, "UID" => $username, "PWD" => $password));Thank you!